# Cron expression with initial delay - Quartz

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am just can figure out how to configure a Cron job in Quartz with initial delay.
So i need something that runs every hour with an initial delay of 10 min.

```
"* * 0/1 * * ?"
```

Comment: What about making the script sleep for a while?

Comment: So how many minutes are there beteen execution? One hour or 70 minutes?

Comment: Do you mean fire once 10 minutes after startup and then every hour thereafter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a late answer, hopefully this helps others. I solved the issue by having 2 scheduled functions in my service class:

```java
@EnableScheduling
public class DeviceService {

    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${devices.update.initial}", fixedDelay = 2592000000L)
    public void initialUpdateDevices() {
        updateDevices();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${devices.update.cron}")
    public void cronUpdateDevices() {
        updateDevices();
    }

    private void updateDevices() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The initial delay and the cron expression are set in application.properties. The fixedDelay is there because Spring doesn't allow initialDelay alone. I set it to 2592000000ms, which is 30 days. In our application, the potential extra update doesn't do any harm.

In application.properties:

```java
devices.update.initial = 600000
devices.update.cron = 0 30 1 * * *
```

Initially run after 10 minutes (60000ms) and then every night at 01:30.

In application-test.properties for unit testing:

```java
devices.update.initial = 86400000
devices.update.cron = 0 30 1 24 12 *
```

None of our unit tests take 1 day to execute so 86400000 milliseconds is a safe bet. The cron "0 30 1 24 12 *" is set to Christmas Eve's night when people should be dreaming of nice things.