# the 'initial-delay' attribute may not be used with cron and trigger tasks

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am building few crons to run, one of the cron i need to run after some time the server has started.

```
<task:scheduled ref="myCron"
            method="processData" cron="0/15 * * * * ?" initial-delay="45000"></task:scheduled>
```

I need to run this cron at every 15 seconds, which it does. But i need to run this cron after 45 seconds server has started and not immediate.

Below is my xsd,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: the 'initial-delay' attribute may not be used with cron and trigger tasks
```

Comment: I faced the same issue and solved it with 2 scheduled functions: one with cron and the other with initialDelayString + fixedDelay. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983486/cron-expression-with-initial-delay-quartz/37447050#37447050.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTasksBeanDefinitionParser.java) of `ScheduledTasksBeanDefinitionParser`, you can see that `cron` and `initial-delay` are not compatible :

```
if (hasInitialDelayAttribute && (hasCronAttribute || hasTriggerAttribute)) {
                parserContext.getReaderContext().error(
                        "the 'initial-delay' attribute may not be used with cron and trigger tasks", taskElement);
                continue; // with the possible next task element
            }
```

You may want to use the *fixed-delay* implementation, e.g :

```
<task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="methodA" fixed-delay="5000" initial-delay="1000"/>
```

See Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) at section *33.3.2 Trigger implementations*

Comment: Really well explained, up to the mark, problem solved.Thanks..!!